# Integration using polar coordinates

Tags: integration

I have to solve this exercise I will describe but I am facing some problems.

$$\int\int_\tau(x+y)\;dx\;dy$$ where $$(x-2)^2 + y^2 \leq 4$$ and $$y\geq0$$

So I am trying to find this integration inside half of a circle.

$\theta$ is from 0 to $\pi/2$ and $r\leq 4 \cos \theta$

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{4\cos\theta}^0r^2(\cos \theta+\sin\theta)\;dr\;d\theta$$

Something is wrong with the plane of integration cause I am getting wierd results.

Comment: You appear to have inverted the limits on the inner integral.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes. I did that because for $\theta=0 r=4$ and for $\theta=\pi/2 r=0$. So you say that the limits are correct but the second one is inverted?

Comment: For any fixed value of $\theta$, the inner end of the slice through the area is at $r=0$, and the outer end is at $r=4\cos\theta$, so $r$ ranges from a low of $0$ to a high of $4\cos\theta$.

Comment: I may be missing something completely, but I get the integral $\int_{r=0}^2 \int_{\theta=-\pi}^{\pi} (2+r \cos \theta + r \sin \theta) r \; dr d\theta$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott can you please show what you mean with a graph? Also you may want to turn your comments into an answer in order to accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Would it not be a lot easier to use the mapping $\phi(r,\theta) = (2+r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$? This way your domain of integration in the new coordinates is $[0,2]\times[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: My lower integration limit on $\theta$ should be $\theta = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's a (fairly crude) picture:

[image]

It shows a ray from the origin at an angle $\theta$ from the positive $x$-axis. When you calculate the inner integral, intuitively speaking you're 'adding up' the values of the function $x+y$ along that ray, so you want $r$ to range from the smallest radius along that ray to the largest one. The smallest one is at $O$, the origin, and is $0$; the largest is at $P$, where the ray intersects the circle $r=4\cos\theta$, and is $4\cos\theta$. Thus, you should have $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{4\cos\theta}r^2(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)\,drd\theta\;.$$

What you did with the inner integral is like trying to find the area under the curve $y=x^2$ between $x=0$ and $x=1$ by calculating $$\int_1^0 x^2\,dx\;.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. That ray thing helped a lot.

Comment: +1 I deleted my answer because it was equivalent and yours is better explained.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi(r,\theta) = (2+r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$, then $|J_{\phi}(r,\theta)| = |r|$,
and $\phi([0,2],[0,\pi]) = \tau$. Use the change of variables formula to get 
$$\int_{\tau} f = \int_{\phi^{-1}(\tau)} f \circ \phi |J_{\phi}|.$$
From this you get 
$$\int_{\tau} x+y \; dx dy = \int_{r=0}^2 \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} (2+r\cos\theta + r\sin\theta)r \; d\theta dr$$
There is a minor technicality with $\phi$ not being invertible at $r=0$ (ie, $(x,y) = (2,0)$), but this is easy to deal with (the measure of $\{(2,0)\}$ is zero, so we may integrate over $\tau \setminus \{(2,0)\}$ instead; then $\phi$ is invertible at all points of interest).

Here's my crude picture:
[image]

Comment: Interesting. I wanted to do something like that or just translate the circle to the 0,0.

Comment: Same thing, basically. Generally, exploiting symmetry is a good thing. In this case, the resulting integral is much simpler to evaluate.